# npm error on installing socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

following a guide for node.js i should install on the prompt via npm the socket.io package

```
npm install socket.io
```

first i got an error saying that it couldn't find msbuild.exe... having installed visual studio 2012 express i read that i should set:

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2012
```

now the error is

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you could add the English translation of those errors. Actually, I believe settings your system language to English helps when programming in general, as errors are easier to find online when written in English, and it will also be easier when following (English) tutorials because you don't have to translate anything.

Comment: i'm sorry it says " the imported project was not found"

Comment: i can't undersand why it's searching microsoft.cpp.default.props from C:\ folder...must i set something else?

Comment: i solved installing visual studio 2013...now i can't figure out why it isn't installing packages inside the folder node_modules